# An exception occurred during loading of business logic

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath

SharePoint 2013, InfoPath error while loading,

> An exception occurred during loading of business logic, 
>   Form ID: urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:infopath:misc:-myXSD-2010-03-31T05-59-04, Type: NullReferenceException, Exception Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.)

We have tried the following:

- DLL property to set `Copy Local = False`
- We have removed InfoPath and installed again
- We tried installing InfoPath to another SharePoint farm, but still no luck.

Environment: SharePoint 2013 Enterprise, Infopath 2010 (Designer)